# JavaScript file doesn't load after page transition with barba.js

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, barbajs

I have a website with a link. When I click the link I want a smooth page transition to the next page using jQuery. I got the the HTML elements inside the barba DOM to fade out. But when the next page tries to load, all BUT the JavaScript loads.

This is my code:
(index.html)

```
   <div id="barba-wrapper" class="wrapper">
    <div class="barba-container">
        <div class="container">
            <span class="text1">Hey There!</span>
            <span class="text2">This is my portfolio!</span>
            <a id="homeLink" href="./home.html">Click me to continue</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $('document').ready(function(){
        var transEffect = Barba.BaseTransition.extend({
            start: function(){
              this.newContainerLoading.then(val => this.fadeInNewcontent($(this.newContainer)));
            },
            fadeInNewcontent: function(nc) {
              nc.hide();
              console.log('stuff should be hidden');
              var $el = $(this.newContainer);
              var _this = this;
              $(this.oldContainer).fadeOut(1000).promise().done(() => {
                nc.css('visibility', 'visible');
                nc.fadeIn(1000, function(){
                console.log('new content should fade in.');
                _this.done();
                })
              });
            }
        });
        Barba.Pjax.getTransition = function() {
          return transEffect;
        }
        Barba.Pjax.start();
    });
</script>
```

I can see the the console logs in the console but JavaScript doesn't load.

This is the page I'm trying to load:
(home.html)

```
<div id="barba-wrapper" class="wrapper">
    <div class="barba-container">
        <canvas></canvas>
        <script src="canvas.js"></script>
    </div>
</div>
```

I get no errors whatsoever.
Also I have seen a question on here with the same problem as mine, but it was very unclear. (and does not have any answers so far)
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In Barba, scripts don't evaluated when loading a new container. It can be done easily using [Events](http://barbajs.org/events.html).

```
Barba.Dispatcher.on('newPageReady', function (currentStatus, oldStatus, container) {
    $(container).find('script').each(function (i, script) {
        var $script = $(script);
        $.ajax({
            url: $script.attr('src'),
            cache: true,
            dataType: 'script',
            success: function () {
                $script.trigger('load');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this line:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML += "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1\">";
```

inside below function

```
fadeInNewcontent: function(nc) {

}
```

Comment: The entire point of Barba.js is removing the leading in of the files, and doing so with Barba to ensure you can animate a transition from page to page. Thus forcing a reload is not the way to go since you will remove the entire purpose of Barba.