# Barbajs Pjax reinitialize jquery

Tags: jquery, pjax, barbajs

I have decided to use *PJAX* namely `Barba js`   plugin .
It works great  but i have a problem  and really need to reinitialize  a bunch of js plugins  on PJAX ready .

I have tried the following code basically it is from Barba js 1.0 where i use the dispatcher and specify on NewPage Ready   create a new script element  and append it to the head of the document .

But it doesn't reinitialize or reload the jquery plugin.

am i missing something or is this not the correct way to reinitialize my  files  ?

```
         Barba.Dispatcher.on('newPageReady', function (currentStatus, 
          oldStatus, container) {

            alert("the alert works ");

            var importeda = document.createElement('script');
            importeda.src ='..js/jquery-1.8.3.js';
            document.head.appendChild(importeda);

  } );
```

Comment: Have you tried a different approach to load the javascript file?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file#answer-950146

Comment: Provide HTML structure which includes barba container and placement of the script tags

Comment: User863 the structure is this  html  https://barba.js.org/v1/demo/nextprev/index.html   except for theres jquery and other scripts loaded after the  barba js .  if you go to page 2 from page one than back .. thats  when the  scripts will  need to be reinitialized ... since pjax is used.

Comment: @user3548161 why not placing the jquery outside the `barba` container. and load other scripts as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54360910/8053274)